# gráfico de barras ggplot 2 vetores lado a lado

Tags: r, ggplot2, barplot

Alguém sabe me dizer se é possivel fazer este gráfico com as barras lado a lado sem utilizar data frames ou "melt"?

```
v1=c(100,120,140)
v2=c(125, 102,104)
a=data.frame(year=factor(2003:2005))

ggplot(data=a, aes(x=year)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = v1, fill = "b"), stat="identity", width=0.3) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = v2, fill = "c"), stat="identity", width=0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("C","13"), values=c("c" = "red","b"="blue")) +
  theme(legend.key=element_rect(fill = "grey"),
        legend.title=element_blank()) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Value")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode deslocar manualmente a posição de qualquer camada usando `position_nudge`. Só precisa ajustar também a largura das barras:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(y = v1),
    stat = "identity",
    fill = "red",
    width = .3,
    position = position_nudge(x = -.15)
  )+
  geom_bar(
    aes(y = v2),
    stat = "identity",
    fill = "blue",
    width = .3,
    position = position_nudge(x = .15)
  )
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]